# Result promise being processed before it executed on Ionic 2 Facebook login

Tags: ionic-framework, promise, facebook-login

I have an Ionic 2 application running the following code on an Angular 2 service:

```
signInWithFacebook(): firebase.Promise<any>
{
    if (this.platform.is('cordova'))
    {
        console.log('Running on cordova...');

        Facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res =>
        {
            const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
            console.log('credential value', facebookCredential);
            var temp = firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);  
            console.log('temp value: ', temp);
            return temp;
        });                     
    }
    else
    {
        return this.auth$.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup
        });
    }

}
```

Then on my login component page I call it like this, on a login button:

```
pubic doFacebookLogin(): void
{
    var temp = this.userDataService.signInWithFacebook()
        .then(() =>
        {
            console.log("Passed here! [1]");

            this.onSignInSuccess();

            console.log("Passed here! [2]");
        });
}
```

My console logs the following when I click the button:

> Running on cordova...
>
> main.js:46695 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at LoginPage.doFacebookLogin (main.js:50920).....
>
> credential value Lf {accessToken: "xxxxxx", provider: "facebook.com"}
>
> temp value:  I {F: 0, ka: undefined, o: I, fa: null, Ma: null…}

The flow I'm expecting is this:

1. call to the `doFacebookLogin()` method
2. call to the `service.signInWithFacebook()` method
    Console logs 'Running on cordova...'
3. step [1] waits for the return promisse of [2]
4. call to `Facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile'])`
5. when the login on [4] is concluded, it calls the `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential()` method, which returns a promise too 
     Console logs 'credential value' and 'temp value'
6. the result promise of [5] is then returned on the `service.signInWithFacebook()` function
7. the `doFacebookLogin()` function finally processes the promise returned on [6] and execute `onSignInSuccess()`

But from the console logs we can see that it's logging 'Running on cordova', then we get an exception on the `.then` call of the first funcion (so the facebook login result promise was not yet processed (so the return promise doesn't exist), and after this the facebook login is processed (and now it exists, but the other function already tried to process it, generating the exception).

What am I missing with these promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just missing a `return`.

```
return Facebook.login(....).then(...);
```

Comment: OMG!! What a shame that I posted it!! But, really, I spent like half a day trying to find it. Now I'm just wondering why Typescript didn't complain that not all paths were returning something... Really thanks!